# How to setcap wifi-menu on arch for non-root users?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, capabilities, setcap

I'm trying to run wifi-menu on arch as non-root. No setcap i've tried works.

```
[root@lilegg johny]# setcap CAP_NET_ADMIN,CAP_SYS_ADMIN,CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE=eip /usr/bin/wifi-menu
[root@lilegg johny]# exit
exit
[johny@lilegg ~]$ wifi-menu 
wifi-menu needs root privileges
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: Capabilities won't help as the UID check is hard-coded into the `wifi-menu` script: `(( EUID == 0 )) || exit_error "${1-$0} needs root privileges"`

Comment: Also note, that setting capabilities on the script itself is useless even if this check would be absent (and even if the kernel supports capabilities on scripts - I'm not sure that this is considered safe and is allowed): the capability won't be inherited by commands requiring the privileges (executed by the script).

Comment: i thought eip can be set to bequeath same permissions to sub-calls. Seems it's usefulness would be pretty limited otherwise.

Comment: @DanilaKiver "not sure that this is considered safe" -- I thought the whole point of setcap is that it's safer than blanket privileged access. "Capabilities allow system administrators to fine-tune what a process is allowed to do, which may help them significantly reduce security risks to their system" https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5737

Comment: @DanilaKiver "the UID check is hard-coded" - so, to overcome this, i can remove the UID and re-compile, correct?

Comment: Making some progress: fakeroot bypasses wifi-menu's user-check. No recompiling needed :) Next, to trace the called executables and setcap them...

Comment: But fakeroot messes up filepaths ...